# Check string into file and extract a part to write it on file in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a log file and i want to extract a line like this from it:

```
ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = 10.10.10.10 and PASS = sdas3asdasd and SN = DFGT5334rFFDS IS RECHARGING NOW
```

After, i want to get only the IP value, Pass value and SN value and write it into another file in this mode :

```
ip;pass;sn
```

How can i do this in bash script with sed or awk?

Thanks

Comment: what (coding) have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, @markp-fusohi, i tried sed but with poor results. 
sed 's/ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = \([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\) and PASS = \([^ ]*\) and SN = \([:alnum:]*\) IS RECHARGING NOW/\1;\2;\3/g' filename

Comment: place your coding attempts in the question along with the (wrong) output it generates; not everyone will take the time to scan the comments and try to piece everything into a single picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data file:

```
$ cat csip.dat
ignore this line
ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = 10.10.10.10 and PASS = sdas3asdasd and SN = DFGT5334rFFDS IS RECHARGING NOW
ignore this line
ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = 85.13.125.158 and PASS = sdwXHWEFFsd and SN = 123abcd__243D IS RECHARGING NOW
ignore this line
```

The OPs `sed` code (from comments) ...

```
$ sed 's/ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}) and PASS = ([^ ]*) and SN = ([:alnum:]*) IS RECHARGING NOW/\1;\2;\3/g' csip.dat
```

... needs a few tweaks:

- add flags `-rn` to allow for extended regex support and to suppress automatic printing of input data to stdout
- change `[:allnum:]` to `[[:alnum:]]`
- change the `/g` to `/p` to change from replacement mode to print mode

The new `sed` command looks like:

```
$ sed -rn 's/ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = ([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}) and PASS = ([^ ]*) and SN = ([[:alnum:]]*) IS RECHARGING NOW/\1;\2;\3/p' csip.dat
10.10.10.10;sdas3asdasd;DFGT5334rFFDS
```

At this point we've accomplished what the OP wanted for the given set of data.

---

Assuming there may be more than one `ERROR_RECHARGING` line to process, and assuming the 3rd field (`sn`) may contain more than just alphanumerics (see 4th line is `csip.date` - above), we can shorten the current `sed` solution and generate 2 sets of output:

```
$ sed -rn 's/ERROR_RECHARGING! =====> THE CS IP = ([^ ]*) and PASS = ([^ ]*) and SN = ([^ ]*) .*/\1;\2;\3/p' csip.dat
10.10.10.10;sdas3asdasd;DFGT5334rFFDS
85.13.125.158;sdwXHWEFFsd;123abcd__243D

# or with some additional shorthand:

$ sed -rn 's/^ERROR_RECHARGING.* = ([^ ]*) .* = ([^ ]*) .* = ([^ ]*) .*/\1;\2;\3/p' csip.dat
10.10.10.10;sdas3asdasd;DFGT5334rFFDS
85.13.125.158;sdwXHWEFFsd;123abcd__243D
```

Where:

- `([^ ]*)` - match a pattern of (space) + (anything_other_than_space) + (space); eliminates lengthy `[0-9]{1,3}` match for ip; also allows us to match on `sn` that contains other non-alphanumerics
- `.* =`  - match anything up to a string of (space) + `=` + (space)

Comment: Thank you very much @markp-fuso !!